Highlight.js: Can't get the styling added to my webpage
I'm trying to get a styled block of code on my website. Highlight.js seems to be what I'm looking for. However when I run my website it doesn't show the layout.
What I've done so far:
1 install it by running "npm install highlight.js"
2 Add it to document app.js:
import hljs from 'highlight.js';

document.querySelectorAll('div.code pre code').forEach((block) => {
    hljs.highlightBlock(block);
});

3 Add it to the document "layout.scss":
@import 'highlight.js/styles/base16-atlas.css';

4 try to run it in my html document:
<div class="code">
  <pre><code class="language-php">
echo "Hoeveel stapels wil je hebben? " . PHP_EOL;
$k = readline("");

for ($i = 0; $i < $k; $i++) {
  for ($j = 0; $j <= $i; $j++) {
      echo "*";
  }
  echo PHP_EOL;
}
  </code></pre>
</div>

5 Outcome is like this:
outcome
I've tried to fix it by changing the html like this:
//imagine the code here
this resulted in: "Syntax error, unexpected token "<", expecting end of file". I've then removed <?php but that resulted in only one line with "hoeveel stapels wil je hebben?"

Looks like you need to just include the highlight js CDN links in your html and you should be good.
From their website:
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/highlight.js/11.9.0/styles/default.min.css">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/highlight.js/11.9.0/highlight.min.js"></script>


<script>hljs.highlightAll();</script>


Hi there! Sorry for the late response but I finally managed to get it to work. I was refering to @import 'highlight.js/styles/base16-chalk-min.css'; but it should've been:
@import 'highlight.js/styles/base16/chalk.min.css';
I did the same thing with your code, added the theme, and now it's working :) (not the most pretiest solution but it works)
Thanks!
